# Is there any way to authenticate a user using cookies in asp.net using form authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, c#-4.0

Is there any way to authenticate user through Cookies....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what the [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) module in ASP.NET uses to track authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer...Is there way to make the timeout period unlimited...